# Outputting a GUID in VBScript ignores all text after it

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, guid

I'm creating a GUID for use in a Classic ASP application, by using TypeLib.  However, even a simple test such as writing the GUID out to the screen is giving me problems - it prints the GUID but ignores everything after it (e.g. HTML tags, additional words, anything).

Here's the rudimentary code to test this:

```
Set typeLib = Server.CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
myGuid = typeLib.Guid
Response.Write myGuid & " is the new GUID"
Set typeLib = Nothing
```

This will display something like *{9DDB27D1-F034-41D7-BB88-D0D811DB91CE}* and that's it; the rest of the text is ignored and isn't written out.  However, if I hard-code that GUID value and reference it from a variable, the rest of the text appears just fine.  I've tried explicit conversion to a String value before displaying, but it still happens.

Comment: Ohh thank god somebody already had this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I seem to have solved my own problem.. it was adding something extra to the text, so I had to do:

```
myGuid = Left(myGuid, Len(myGuid)-2)
```

and it now outputs fine.  Strange.

Comment: Not that strange if the GUID really is a struct.  The Left function would have to convert it to a string, so it can work with it and return a string.

Comment: Scriptlet.TypeLib.Guid gives a null-terminated string. Something on the way from your code to the screen uses null termination and thus stops outputing things in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

I use something like this

```
Function GetGuid() 
        Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib") 
        GetGuid = Left(CStr(TypeLib.Guid), 38) 
        Set TypeLib = Nothing 
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

It adds a vbNullChar or Chr(0) at the end of the GUID. Replace(myGuid, Chr(0), "") will fix it. Better than using Left or Mid functions.

Answer (score -2):

GUID is a struct and not a string, you need to add a ToString() method to output it as a string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Response.Write myGuid.ToString("D")
```

Comment: I don't think I can use ToString in VBScript; trying to use typeLib.Guid.ToString() gives me an error.