# How to generate a GUID in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, guid, uuid

I want to generate GUID strings in VBScript. I know that there's no built-in function in VBScript for generating one. I don't want to use random-generated GUIDs. Maybe there is an ActiveX object that can be created using CreateObject() that is sure to be installed on (newer) Windows versions that can generate a GUID?

Comment: I think the accepted answer has much lower quality than the [highest voted one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/968790/2932052). Maybe a reason to rethink your decision?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[How Can I Create a GUID Using a Script? (in: Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/02/21/how-can-i-create-a-guid-using-a-script/) says this:

```
Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
Wscript.Echo TypeLib.Guid
```

However, note that Scriptlet.TypeLib.Guid returns a null-terminated string, which can cause some things to [ignore everything after the GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/413367/8446). To fix that, you might need to use:

```
Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
myGuid = TypeLib.Guid
myGuid = Left(myGuid, Len(myGuid)-2)
Wscript.Echo myGuid
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the "Hey, Scripting Guy!" link!

Comment: For anyone using this method, be aware that the `Scriptlet.TypeLib` object will return _the same GUID_ each time you invoke the `GUID` property. If you need to generate multiple GUIDs, destroy and recreate the `Scriptlet.TypeLib` object or, better yet, wrap it in a function like others have shown so the object is created and destroyed with each function call.

Comment: @vividos broken link is fixed now (thanks to Google)

Answer (score 58):

```
Function CreateGUID
  Dim TypeLib
  Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
  CreateGUID = Mid(TypeLib.Guid, 2, 36)
End Function
```

This function will return a plain GUID, e.g., `47BC69BD-06A5-4617-B730-B644DBCD40A9`.

If you want a GUID in a registry format, e.g., `{47BC69BD-06A5-4617-B730-B644DBCD40A9}`, change the function's last line to

```
CreateGUID = Left(TypeLib.Guid, 38)
```

Comment: Best answer: combines providing a not too smart function and adding additional material for information about the details. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Worked best for me.

Answer (score 10):

```
' Returns a unique Guid on every call. Removes any cruft.
Function CreateGuid()
    CreateGuid = Left(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").Guid,38)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Set tlib = Server.CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
strGuid = tlib.Guid
```