# Can't concatenate a guid in between strings in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function in VBA to check whether a file exists. If the file exists, I need to rename the file by concatenating a guid after the file name. However, when I try to add the guid between the file name and file type, it will not keep anything that comes after the guid. For example, if the original file name is "test.xlsx", the function will rename the file to "test{guid}" without the .xlsx.

```
Sub fileExists()
    Dim TypeLib As Object
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim NeNewPath As String
    Dim guid As String
    Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
    guid = TypeLib.guid
    guid = Replace(guid, "{", "")
    guid = Replace(guid, "}", "")
    FilePath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\excel\test.xlsx"
    NewPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\excel\test" & guid & ".xlsx"
    If Dir(FilePath) <> "" Then
        Name FilePath As NewPath
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think it's because GUID generated from TypeLib.Guid is a null terminated string based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968756/how-to-generate-a-guid-in-vbscript which would result in everything after the GUID being dropped.

Comment: @xQbert I agree, The `Left(guid, Len(guid)-2)` is all that is missing, which is from your link

Comment: Thank you @xQbert, that fixed it!!

Comment: Glad we could help.  I'm actively NOT answering this question as I truly believe it's a duplicate :P

Comment: Yes I believe so to, and have marked it as a duplicate.